# matplotlib and the factorial function

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, factorial

Is there a direct way to plot the factorial function using matplotlib? I'd like to plot x^5 and 45n! together.

I tried using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
plt.plot(x, x**5)
plt.plot(x, 45*math.factorial(x))
```

but the factorial part doesn't graph. Any ideas?

Comment: For 1, `math.factorial` only accepts integer values.

Comment: "doesn't graph" is very vague, do you get any errors?  I do and they say exactly what's wrong.  i.e. what @Groger said!

Comment: I get: `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: @JacobIRR I get that same error message. I'm a bit new to using python in general. So, a follow up question is, am I able to graph is using integer values? I suppose I would be using a scatter plot, but can I make it look continuous some how?

Comment: If you use `numpy`, always check if there's a special `numpy` function for your purpose, e.g. `numpy.math.factorial`. Likewise `np.sqrt` instead of `math.sqrt`. Sometimes these point to the same implementation, but it saves you from installing/importing another package. And you can visit the documentation to see examples on how to use the function with numpy arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 things about your code:

1. I think `math` functions only accept scalars (`int`, `float`, etc), not list or numpy array.
2. The factorial function is defined for (positive) integers only, not for float, e.g. `0.5`.

I think you are looking for the [`gamma` function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), which extends the factorial function over the real numbers:

```
from scipy.special import gamma

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
plt.plot(x,gamma(x), label='Factorial')
plt.plot(x, x**5, label='$x^5$')

xx = np.arange(11)
plt.scatter(xx, gamma(xx))
plt.legend()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much!